# ASP Round function not behaving as expected

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript, rounding

I'm rounding up my decimal values to integer values
ex:

I have 5 numbers whose % sum should end up being 100% but i get 101% my values are

```
11.11111, 80.55555, 5.55555, 2.77777
```

and on rounding them i get

```
11, 81, 6, 3 => 101
```

In above for example 5.555556 rounds up to 6 (correct value) but is screwing up my total for percentage which is going above 100 when i round and add numbers.
How can i force or change round function to give desired value?
I'm using

```
round(100 * (x1/sum) )
```

My output on webpage is like: (i want to display % rounded up to int)

```
field value %
x      8    11
y      58   81
```

Is this not possible?

Note: I'm using asp round function -
updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think 5.55556 should round to 5? Rounding algorithms round up OR down, depending on which integer is closest. Clearly 6 is closer to 5.55556 than 5 is (it's great than 5.5,) so 6 is the expected and correct answer.

Take a look at the floor and ceil functions for alternative implementations of always rounding down and always rounding up respectively.

-Oisin

Comment: unless the function somehow knows about all the numbers involved, you're asking the impossible.

Comment: So, I know this is an old question, but for anyone looking this question up, Floor/Ceiling is not the issue here.  It is because rounding by its very nature introduces a margin of error. Floor will result in a 98 and Ceiling in a 102. Based on the repeating numbers, I suspect that those numbers are actually derived by something/9 which creates a continuously repeating number. In cases where you have cleanly terminating decimals like 11.3+80.6+5.4+2.7 = 100, rounding is fine, but with certain fractions, you get this error because you round once to get to decimal values, and again for the total.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like 5.556 should round to 6, actually. Maybe your school taught math differently?

Comment: nope i know it should round to 6 :D
I was basing my answer on end result. I have 5 numbers whose % sum should end up being 100% but i get 101% 
my values are 11.11111, 80.55555, 5.55555, 2.77777 and on rounding them i get 11, 81, 6, 3 => 101

Comment: @Rahuls: You could write your own rounding function which makes .5 go down and .6 go up. But this will still get you errors where your sum could be 99. Is there a reason you need to round before the addition?

Comment: yes i want values without decimal and that is why i was rounding them. i have number and its percentage displayed in a table with total at end.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mistyped, but 5.55556 should actually round UP to 6 (anything .5 and above rounds up, and anything below .5 rounds down).  If you want better control, then I would look into the floor and ciel functions.  floor always rounds down and ciel always rounds up.

Comment: I don't think classic ASP has the floor and ceiling functions, so you would have to write your own implementation.

Comment: It seems that what you're really trying to do is 2 separate things.  One - you want each value to be rounded.  Two - you want the sum of all values to be rounded.  I would round the sum of all pre-rounded numbers to get your total.

Answer (score 1):

You should add all your values then do the rounding.

By nature, rounding gives you a little more or a little less. So if you add values that all are a little more you will get over 100.

Comment: yes i understand i have to add and do rounding, but my requirement is such that i have to round them up individually. 

Is round not good solution here? SHould i do it some other way

Comment: Without knowing the exact problem/requirement it's hard to just guess at a solution

Answer (score 1):

VB (and VBScript / ASP 3) uses banker's rounding (or "round to the nearest even") so:

```
1.5 rounds to 2
2.5 rounds to 2
3.5 rounds to 3
4.5 rounds to 4
... etc.
```

I would suggest doing as Jim Schubert suggested and writing your own rounding function to round properly.

This page has some good info about rounding across all vb-esque languages:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196652

Answer (score 1):

If you do individual roundings, and than want the total to be some exact number too, the last individual number must always be the end-result minus all previous rounded numbers.

This is the case in ASP but also the case in Excel f.i. AFAIK this is the only way to achiveve this.

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
round(100m * (x1/sum) )
```

which should force both factors to be treated as decimals instead of ints. Also, make sure `(x1/sum)` doesn't have a greater number in the denominator.